# What's the derogatory word for a person who doesn't leave you alone

Tags: single-word-requests

The kind of person who sticks to you all the time, like a chewing gum. You want to get rid of him, but at every party he comes and joins your group. And he just doesn't get the message that people don't want him around.

In hindi we call him a "chep" (sticky)

Comment: My first thought was 'stalker' - but the obsessiveness is not quite the same degree in your question, so not quite right I would say.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can describe that kind of person as ***[clingy](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/clingy)***:

> - wanting to be with another person all the time in a way that is annoying.

(MacMillan Dictionary)

Answer (score 3):

A [hanger-on](https://www.wordnik.com/words/hanger-on).

> from WordNet 3.0 Copyright 2006 by Princeton University. All rights
>   reserved.
>
> n. someone who persistently (and annoyingly) follows along

Answer (score 0):

A [pesterer](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/pesterer) : "agent noun of pester; one who pesters."

Comment: Or you could say they are ‘a pest’.

Answer (score 0):

A [nudnik](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nudnik).

> A pestering, nagging, or irritating person; a bore.

(OED)