# Help with a good word to describe a personality

Tags: single-word-requests, epithet-requests

I am a member of a maker space in a large city. It is something of a club where people work on different projects together. Recently I encountered several individuals who were being obnoxious and not fun to be around. They showed up at different times attempting to gain entry and become part of the group. All of them exhibited very similar personality characteristics, and as I was trying to communicate this to a friend of mine, I realized there isn't a word that I know that describes this personality characteristic.

This is a description of one specific individual's behavior (others had very similar traits):

He showed up unannounced to the space and attempted to insert himself into the group by announcing loudly that they are the expert in their chosen field. When they felt he was not getting attention due to him, he attempted to engage members in random conversation and strike a loud argument with them, to prove their superiority (extreme attention seeking, and one-upmanship) He behaved as though he was inherently superior and deserved immediate admiration and recognition. Finally when those attempts were ignored he proceeded to cause attention to himself in other ways, such as interrupting other members' work by asking question such as "where can I find a /piece of equipment here/". He got increasingly frustrated when he didn't get an answer he was looking for, it seemed like he just couldn't comprehend the meaning of "open community" and wanted to be served and assisted. This person clearly lacked understanding of social norms and cues, but rather than attempting to gain understanding of the situation he chose to act as though he was not required to abide by our silly social conventions. He simply didn't understand why people couldn't just accept him and give him what he wants.

I feel like there should be a word to describe this individual, or this personality trait. I have definitely experienced something similar more than once.

Comment: Sounds like a Stack Exchange newbie. (Oops! Did I say that?)

Comment: Loosely related: [What's the (derogatory) word for a person who doesn't leave you alone](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/386729/26083)

Answer (score 0):

**Haughty** comes to mind:

unfriendly and seeming to consider yourself better than other people

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/haughty

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like **narcissism** in one of its many forms. There is something called [Narcissistic Personality Disorder](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_personality_disorder), which is at least recognizable and to some extent manageable, in the sense that you can respond to it in a more emotionally detached way.

There are plenty of **obnoxious jerks** in the world, and they’re a huge drain on the mental energy of people that have to deal with them. However, their very prevalence has spawned a huge literature of coping strategies. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**Brash** sounds appropriate.

> self-assertive in a rude, noisy, or overbearing way.

[GOOG](https://www.google.com/search?q=brash)